# android studio run or debug: apk does not contain java classes

Tags: android-studio, debugging, apk

Inside android studio:

build APK: size 7M including everything declared in build.gradle, as expected.

But if run/debug, the APK built is about 700K, which does not contain java classes (seen from APK analyzer).

How does it work?

Comment: What if you build from Gradle directly in command line?

Comment: Same as build APK as expected, containing everything.

Comment: It's probably Instant Run moving your classes somewhere else where it can swap them later. Although I couldn't find any info about where they are being stored exactly.